# How to connect Google Cloud Composer (Airflow) with Google Sheets and extract the info to Google Storage (bucket)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to read a google sheet such as:

STORE_NUM | STORE_NAME | OPENING_AT | CLOSING_AT
01 | name_a | 9:00 | 20:00
02 | name_b | 9:00 | 20:00
03 | name_c | 9:00 | 20:00
04 | name_d | 9:00 | 20:00

from which I want to read only the rows corresponding to A3 and D5 (STORE_NUM is the first row, i.e. cell A1), once read, I want to make a file with it (csv, avro, etc.) which then be placed in a GCS Bucket, then I will read the file in the bucket and "sink" it to BigQuery.

I need to do so using Composer (Airflow), so far I'm with a **not working** script such as:

```
import datetime
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.sheets_to_gcs import GoogleSheetsToGCSOperator

BUCKET = "name_of_the_bucket"
SPREADSHEET_ID = "sheet_id" # <- How to add the sheet's name and range? e.g. ShName!A5:C10

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime.datetime.today(),
    #'end_date': ,
    'email': ['some_person_name@some_company_name.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': True,
    #'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
    }   

sch_interval = "00 10 * * 1"

dag = DAG(
    'GSh_to_GCS_lab',
    default_args=default_args,
    tags=["example"],
    catchup=False,
    schedule_interval=sch_interval)

upload_sheet_to_gcs = GoogleSheetsToGCSOperator(
    task_id="upload_sheet_to_gcs",
    destination_bucket=BUCKET,
    spreadsheet_id=SPREADSHEET_ID,
    gcp_conn_id='google_cloud_default',
    dag=dag
)

start = DummyOperator(task_id='Starting', dag=dag)

start >> upload_sheet_to_gcs
```

So far I'm getting troubles with the authentication, but I could have some other errors that I'm not able to identify yet.

I'm working with:

[image]

I've read some documentation but, being honest, I can't get the whole information together to make it right.

I'm quite new to both Composer and Airflow so, please, be as detailed as possible. How can I get done what I need? At least the first phase (reading from GSh and load the info as a file in a bucket)

Any helpful information that get me closer will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the part of loading Google sheets to a bucket using this script:

```
import datetime

from airflow import models
from airflow.operators import bash
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.sheets_to_gcs import GoogleSheetsToGCSOperator

YESTERDAY = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
BUCKET = 'your-target-bucket'
SHEET_ID = '<google_sheet_id>'

default_args = {
    'owner': 'Composer Example',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': [''],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=5),
    'start_date': YESTERDAY,
}

with models.DAG(
        'drive_to_gcs',
        catchup=False,
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(days=1)) as dag:

    # Print the dag_run id from the Airflow logs
    #print_dag_run_conf = bash_operator.BashOperator(
        #task_id='print_dag_run_conf', bash_command='echo {{ dag_run.id }}')
    upload_sheet_to_gcs = GoogleSheetsToGCSOperator(
        task_id="upload_sheet_to_gcs",
        destination_bucket=BUCKET,
        spreadsheet_id=SHEET_ID,
        gcp_conn_id='google_cloud_default'
    )

    upload_sheet_to_gcs
```

Just make sure that the service account used in the creation of your Composer environment is added as an editor in your google sheet:

[image]

[image]

Enable [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api).
Add `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` in API scope upon the creation of your environment as per this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing#OAuth2Authorizing) and use version Airflow 2 for image version:

[image]

Output:

```
*** Reading remote log from gs://us-central1-case-20220331-fde8f6be-bucket/logs/drive_to_gcs/upload_sheet_to_gcs/2022-03-31T06:37:38.140371+00:00/1.log.
[2022-03-31, 06:37:45 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1033} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: drive_to_gcs.upload_sheet_to_gcs manual__2022-03-31T06:37:38.140371+00:00 [queued]>
[2022-03-31, 06:37:45 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1033} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: drive_to_gcs.upload_sheet_to_gcs manual__2022-03-31T06:37:38.140371+00:00 [queued]>
[2022-03-31, 06:37:45 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1239} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2022-03-31, 06:37:45 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1240} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 2
[2022-03-31, 06:37:45 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1241} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2022-03-31, 06:37:45 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1260} INFO - Executing <Task(GoogleSheetsToGCSOperator): upload_sheet_to_gcs> on 2022-03-31 06:37:38.140371+00:00
[2022-03-31, 06:37:45 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:52} INFO - Started process 2572 to run task
[2022-03-31, 06:37:45 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:76} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'drive_to_gcs', 'upload_sheet_to_gcs', 'manual__2022-03-31T06:37:38.140371+00:00', '--job-id', '33', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/20220331.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmpia0bpqnu', '--error-file', '/tmp/tmpjioqxsfk']
[2022-03-31, 06:37:45 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:77} INFO - Job 33: Subtask upload_sheet_to_gcs
[2022-03-31, 06:37:46 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:109} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: drive_to_gcs.upload_sheet_to_gcs manual__2022-03-31T06:37:38.140371+00:00 [running]> on host airflow-worker-7b5f8fc749-nxcfg
[2022-03-31, 06:37:46 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1426} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_EMAIL=
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=Composer Example
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=drive_to_gcs
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=upload_sheet_to_gcs
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2022-03-31T06:37:38.140371+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=manual__2022-03-31T06:37:38.140371+00:00
[2022-03-31, 06:37:47 UTC] {credentials_provider.py:312} INFO - Getting connection using `google.auth.default()` since no key file is defined for hook.
[2022-03-31, 06:37:48 UTC] {credentials_provider.py:312} INFO - Getting connection using `google.auth.default()` since no key file is defined for hook.
[2022-03-31, 06:37:48 UTC] {gcs.py:518} INFO - File /tmp/tmp6amutoi9 uploaded to 20220331_Sheet1.csv in case_20200301 bucket
[2022-03-31, 06:37:48 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1268} INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS. dag_id=drive_to_gcs, task_id=upload_sheet_to_gcs, execution_date=20220331T063738, start_date=20220331T063745, end_date=20220331T063748
[2022-03-31, 06:37:48 UTC] {local_task_job.py:154} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
[2022-03-31, 06:37:48 UTC] {local_task_job.py:264} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

Uploaded in bucket:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Anjela. If, later, you figure out how to select the range of the sheet to be read, and want to expand your answer, I'll appreciated it. The key was to "build" a new Composer. I thought that scopes could be somehow added within the script.

Comment: So far I've seen that within the `GoogleSheetsToGCSOperator` I can use the parameter `sheet_filter='sheet_name'` to select the sheet I want to export, avoiding to export all the sheets, nevertheless, the following filter doesn't work as expected `sheet_filter='sheet_name!A5:D9'` due to the fact that the exporting results in the same as if only the sheet's name were specified, rather than exporting the selected range only.

Comment: @Mike, for that other concern, you may post it as another SO question so that the community can easily navigate answers to questions.